# Place a break in a repeater

Tags: c#, sql

I have two repeaters. First one returns all customer transactions while the second one returns the notes entered in the system for that particular customer. The problem is that when a customer has more than one note for a particular month the payment transaction table will repeat the transaction according to the note table. Example if the note table has for the month of March 10 notes, then I will see in the payment table 10 transactions (all the same). How can I generate the notes separate from the payment transactions?

Thank you!

```
  protected void FillNotesTable()
    {

        string connection = @"Data Source=###; User ID = ###; Password=###; Initial Catalog = ###; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetCurrentCustomerNotes", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();

            // User input
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@CID"].Value = tbCustomerID.Text;

            repeaterNotes.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            repeaterNotes.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

}

```
 protected void GetDataUnit()
    {
        string userName = Environment.UserName;
        userName = Request.Cookies["###"]["User"];
        tbFPN.Text = userName;

        string connection = @"Data Source=###t; User ID = ###; Password=###; Initial Catalog = ###; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetCurrentCustomerByUnit", conn))

            try
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();

                // User input
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UN", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@UN"].Value = tbSearchNumber.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FPN", userName));

                // Return info
                SqlDataReader objDR;
                objDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (objDR.Read())
                {
                    tbCustomerID.Text = objDR["ID"].ToString();
                    tbCertNumber.Text = objDR["Cert_Number"].ToString();
                    tbReturnUnit.Text = objDR["Unit_Number"].ToString();
                    tbReturnName.Text = objDR["Customer_Name"].ToString();               
                    tbReturnAddress.Text = objDR["Address"].ToString();
                    tbReturnCity.Text = objDR["City"].ToString();
                    tbReturnState.Text = objDR["State_Abbr"].ToString();
                    tbReturnZipCode.Text = objDR["ZIP_Code"].ToString();
                    tbReturnPhone.Text = objDR["Phone_Number"].ToString();
                    tbReturnEmail.Text = objDR["Email_Address"].ToString();

                }
                objDR.Close();

                repeaterPayments.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                repeaterPayments.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage1.Text = ex.Message;
                lblMessage1.Visible = true;
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you're getting one data table back, but should be getting two - a master and a salve, and then using a [nested repeater to display that hierarchical data](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154).

Comment: Thank you David. I forgot to mention that the Notes Table has nothing to do with the unit. Maybe this will help you advise something else. The Notes Table in the database has only the customer ID to recognize which customer has that note. The payments table as the unit and customer id and I created two different stored procedures to get that data out. I guess what I want is to break the payments table repeater when it reaches the number of transaction found in the database. Hope this clears more.